Use of EU Blue card as Schengen visa if moved out of issuing country
I have a valid EU Blue Card issued by Germany. I have however moved to UK on high skilled worker visa.
Can I use my Blue card to travel in the Schengen countries until its expiration (although I am no longer a resident of Germany)?

I believe that you should inform the issuing authority (the Ausländerbehörde whereever you lived) that you no longer qualify for a Blue Card, and have the card cancelled (§51 (1) 6. AufenthG). You left Germany to take a job elsewhere, so 7. does not apply.
